# WooCommerce Category and Attributes linked and filtered

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I´m setting up a WooCommerce website and would like to have a special feature that I don´t know if there is a plugin alaredy done or I need to do it myself (but I have no idea if possible and how).

In a example, I have a store that sell t-shirts, and it can be from various color and size as well various fabric type. To make less confuse for clients, I would like to setup the fabric types as category and the colors and sizes as attributes. But the same t-shirt model can be available in all fabrics, with some different colors and/or sizes, and I would to not have to duplicate each entry, but instead, have all linked in a way the customer once he choose the fabric (the category) he only see the attributes available for that category...

So resuming, let´s say I have 1 model of t-shirts, and 3 different fabrics. That t-shirt model can be made of each fabric type. And each model has specifics colors available

```
Fabric A -> Model 1 -> Colors Blue and red
Fabric B -> Model 1 -> Colors Green
Fabric C -> Model 1 -> Colos yellow
```

And I can have more produts (Models)

```
Fabric A -> Model 2 -> Colors Blue
Fabric B -> Model 2 -> Colors Green and Green
Fabric C -> Model 2 -> Colos yellow
```

etc...

Is there a way to acomplish this using WooCommerce ? And how ?

let me know if you need more details !

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has built in function to set up this feature. You can set this products as variable products. To get more details about how to set up variable product visit following link http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/

Comment: Hi, yes, I used variable products, but there is a way to have same products with different variables according to the category ?